# Charles Proxy Issue on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, proxy, charles-proxy

I am trying to do a debug session on my App (Android) by monitoring the outbound/inbound HTTP traffic.

I have followed these steps for the setup,

- Made sure that my phone and laptop are in same network.
- My laptop runs Ubuntu. So, I took my laptop's IP address from `ifconfig`. Let's say it was `172.x.x.x`.
- Configured this IP as the Proxy IP in my mobile, with port `8888`.
- Then, finally, having Charles Application running, I was hoping that my HTTP traffic would get routed via Charles Application on my laptop and I would be able to see the URLs referred.

**Issues,**

- I cannot see my traffic in Charles Proxy application.
- When I look into `Help -> Local IP Address`, I see that the IP is `127.0.0.1` and not `172.x.x.x`.
- But in my friend's laptop, who also has same setup, we see `172.x.x.x` as the Local IP Address.

**What am I doing wrong here? Does `/etc/hosts` affect this setup in anyway?**

Comment: I also have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi BBC :). yeah I have found the solution. Sorry I didn't put it here. In my case, I was in office WIFI when I was trying to use charles. The VPN was not connected properly. I had to connect to the VPN from VPN software (like how you access office VPN from home). Then it started reflecting the actual IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found couple of solutions for this. Both will work -

Note down your actual IP address from the IFConfig.

[image]

My actual IP here is `172.16.16.22`.

1. In your mobile wifi's proxy connection, enter this above IP address and 8888 as port value. You will start seeing traffic in the charle's proxy application.
2. If you are in office WIFI, it is probable that VPN has some issue. In such cases, connect to the VPN from the VPN software provided to you by your office. This will follow same procedure as you would connect to your office network (VPN) from your Home WIFI.

Comment: I was trying something similar to solution 1 as you mentioned BUT using ProxyDroid. Now that I used your manual approach it works! Many thanks, Arunko! EDIT: Charles stills shows 127.0.0.1 as my local IP address though. But I guess it doesn't matter!

Comment: Thank you BBC :). Anyway it doesn't matter if charles shows as loopback address. If you could, please post this issue to Charles issue tracker. I am too lazy to do that :P.  Also could you please mark this answer as accepted? It helps!

Comment: Thanks, Arunko! I gave you an upvote but I cannot mark the answer as accepted as you are the original poster (you should be the one to mark it as accepted). Thanks again!